# zsh how to backspace through quotes

Tags: zsh

How can I backspace and move through quotes in zsh?

Pressing `left` or `backspace` does nothing at the start of the quote after I hit enter after typing `'`:

```
$ echo '                  
quote>
```

The only way I know to re-edit the stuff before the quote is to hit `control c`, but I don't think it's very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `push-line-or-edit` widget, then you can edit the complete command:

> **push-line-or-edit**
>             At the top-level (PS1) prompt, equivalent to push-line.  At a secondary (PS2) prompt, move the entire  current  multiline  construct
>             into the editor buffer.  The latter is equivalent to push-input followed by get-line.

This widget is not bound to any key by default, so use

```
bindkey "^[q" push-line-or-edit
```

to bind it to `ESC-q`. (This key combination is bound to `push-line` when using the emacs key bindings, so if you use `push-line` regularly choose another key combination.)

A small Demonstration (■ indicates the cursor):

```
$ bindkey "^[q" push-line-or-edit
$ echo ' [Enter]
[ quote ] ■ [ESC-q]
$ echo '
■ [up arrow]
$ ■echo '
```